# How to start and stop jetty with maven

Tags: java, maven-2, jetty

I would like to start and stop jetty with maven.

This is my setup http://nopaste.info/61ef12198d.html

With `mvn jetty:run` my jetty starts locally but when I want to run jetty in test-phase with `mvn -Pselenium test` jetty doesn't run.

Answer (score 2):

The "Maven way" would be to run your Selenium tests during the `integration-test` phase and to start and stop Jetty respectively during the `pre-integration-test` and `post-integration-test` phases.

There are several ways to implement such a configuration, see [Integration and Functional Testing with Maven 2.0](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Maven+and+Integration+Testing) for one approach.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that you would have to bind an execution of `jetty:run` to a phase that runs before `test`. My guess would be `process-test-classes`. See [Maven Lifecycle Reference](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference).

Comment: and how should i start then? With mvn -Pselenium test?

Comment: sure, that should do it. add the plugin execution to the profile, obviously

Comment: see Pascal's answer. The configuration required can be found here: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Maven+Jetty+Plugin (header: **Automatic execution of the plugin**)